# Is there a way to assign value to deeply nested property of object using a string?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, recursion

So let's say there is an object `a`:

```
let a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: {
        e: null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The task is to create a method which would be assigning a value to `a`-object's property by property's path that will be passed into method as string.
So expected result is:

**Method**

```
let magicMethod = ({prop, value}) => {
  /*magic here*/
}
```

**Call:**

```
magicMethod({prop: 'b.c.d.e', value: true})
```

**Result (console.log(a)):**

```
{
  b: {
    c: {
      d: {
        e: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It should work for all deepness levels, so call `magicMethod({prop: 'b.c', value: true})` should modify `a`-object to:

```
{
  b: {
    c: true
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve such behavior via recursion or something else?

So far, i did manage to implement it with this approach:
[image]

But it is not flexible and, to be honest, i don't like it at all :)
I have a feeling that there are some smarter solutions.

Comment: Also related (the one i usually take as dupe link): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arays-by-string-path

Comment: eval('a.b.c.d.e=true')  ??  i.e. eval (yourString + " = " + value) - which will work if structure exists that you specified in yourString, and is in scope

Comment: @developer it works, but disregards major security concerns regarding `eval`, therefore is often not applicable.

Comment: @ASDFGerte point taken - However, the security concerns are usually in respect of unknown content being evaluated - in this situation the eval is on a known structure  inside the yourString variable/structure in my comment

Comment: @ASDFGerte: Note that your related question is about *getting* value by a dot-path.  This one is about *setting* a value.  Not that they're unrelated, but it will probably be very different code.

Comment: @developer: Even ignoring the mantra that *eval is evil*, that won't work if some of the intermediate nodes are missing.  Try it on `{a : b: {}}`, for instance.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - you should read my comment closer - specifically the bit where i say: "will work if structure exists that you specified in yourString, and is in scope."  (all the second half)

Comment: @developer: That simply means that this technique is less useful than those described in many related questions.  But `eval` might already be disqualifying.  There are environments that prohibit any version of `eval` (even the Function constructor) altogether.